# Comma use with present participle

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? Should I use a comma after "away" or not?

> She looks away thinking.
>
> She looks away, thinking.

Comment: Where is the idiom or phrasal verb here?

Comment: @stangdon I edited the post's title to make it more accurate.

Answer (score -1):

The correct one is: `She looks away, thinking.`

A comma denotes a moment of pause in a sentence that can be used to separate ideas or grammatical structures.
Commas can be used in several different ways. Separating parallel adjectives, setting off nonrestrictive phrases, separating items in a list, and separating an introductory phrase from the rest of a sentence are some illustrations of common uses.

**Incorrect**

> Prior to the scandal the governor’s approval rating was high.

**Correct**

> Prior to the scandal, the governor’s approval rating was high.

**Incorrect**

> He was a difficult stubborn child.

**Correct**

> He was a difficult, stubborn child.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that it's "incorrect" not to have a comma after a "fronted" adverbial clause like ***Prior to the scandal***. Syntactically, that's no different to most written instances of ***Before that** we lived [somewhere else]* - where I haven't made any attempt to count them up, but I'd guess it's far more common ***not*** to include a comma. Such commas are only there to reflect pauses in speech - so if you wouldn't pause there, no comma should be used.

Comment: There are many different notions regarding these terms. However, as a non-native speaker, I try to be cautious and post anything based on a proper reference; I used the [Rules for comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/) blog reference and not my personal opinion. @FumbleFingers

Comment: If those "rules" are what caused you to make your incorrect assertion as flagged up above, they're not helpful. To be honest, though, I've no idea whether the fact of not being a native Anglophone means it's meaningless for you to consider whether you'd introduce a pause in speech within utterances like this.

Comment: I see; that was a mistake, I believe. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I perhaps overstated the case in my first comment. In my *second* comment I deliberately put commas before and after the [entirely optional] conjunction ***though*** when I wrote ***To be honest, though, I've no idea...***  - even though if I *vocalise* the text to myself, I would rarely pause at all *before* the conjunction (but I nearly always would *after* it). Increasing numbers of writers today *wouldn't* include that first comma, but I'm getting on a bit myself, and old habits die hard. So *that* comma is there even though it doesn't reflect a pause for me!

Comment: Imagine someone is originally from an Orwellian country where people have to speak and write in the Persian language with no punctuation marks. Regardless, their mother language is Azeri because of geolocation. Then you have to migrate to another country and start speaking Turkish, with entirely different characters and grammar. Yet, on the other hand, you need to learn and speak English too. Of course, it would be naive to assume that the reasons mentioned above are concrete, but being native makes it easier to assimilate some concepts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers " Such commas are only there to reflect pauses in speech". No, that it very much not true. Commas are governed by grammatical rules. And it is incorrect to not put commas after fronted adverbial phrases. If you want to make a descriptivist argument that "lots of people don't put a comma in", okay, but prescriptively, it is incorrect. Moreover, including the comma makes it easier to read.

Comment: "Imagine someone is originally from an Orwellian country where people have to speak and write in the Persian language" If it's an Orwellian country, wouldn't they be speaking Newspeak?

Comment: We don't speak the Newspeak. However, we felt some fullwise plusungoods which is hard to believe to the oldspeakers. As an example, telescreen is real.

Comment: @Acccumulation: My approach to linguistics is pretty much 100% descriptive - I don't really have any time for *prescriptive* grammar in general. The comma before "though" that I mentioned earlier is one of the very few concessions I make to (largely arbitrary / historical) orthographic conventions. And despite being a Literary Studies graduate, I barely recognise writing as "language" subject to the rules of "grammar" - real language is *spoken*, and writing is just a poor attempt to represent it, imho.

Comment: @Mohi: I can't really follow your "Orwellian" point there. I recall that 50 years ago I was deeply suspicious of Chomsky's "universal grammar" ideas as were being being taught to us as undergraduates, but it seems to have taken most of the decades since then for everyone else to agree with my perspective! But even if "universal grammar" is a busted flush, it seems likely to me that people might at least *tend* to pause at "the same" positions within complex utterances, because regardless of which language you're using, many sub-elements will "map / correspond" to the same in other languages.